# R: how to increase the distance between label and boxplot

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray", names = c("Apple \n Sauce", "Banana", "Candy", "Dandelion", "Eve", "Fox"))
```

The above code gives me:

[image]

I have a multi-line label, "Apple Sauce", but I don't know how to space it correctly so that the label is not overlaid on top of the boxplot. How can I increase the distance between the label and the boxplot?

**Edit:** Suppose I want to remove one of the boxplots

```
newInsectSprays <- InsectSprays[1:60,]
boxplot(count ~ spray, data=newInsectSprays, col="lightgray", xaxt="n")
axis(1, axTicks(1), labels=F)
mtext(c("Apple\nSauce", "Banana\n", "Candy\n", "Dandelion\n", "Eve\n"), 
      1, 2, at=axTicks(1))
```

This code repeats the "Apple Sauce" label. How do I fix this?[image]

**Edit 2:**

```
newInsectSprays <- InsectSprays[1:60,]
boxplot(newInsectSprays$count[newInsectSprays$spray == "A"], 
        newInsectSprays$count[newInsectSprays$spray == "B"],
        newInsectSprays$count[newInsectSprays$spray == "C"],
        col="lightgray", xaxt="n")
mtext(c("Apple\nSauce", "Banana\n", "Candy\n"), 
      1, 2, at=axTicks(1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a custom x axis. We may want to avoid spaces, and add `\n` to the end of the other strings too, to get a cleaner result.

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data=InsectSprays, col="lightgray", xaxt="n")
axis(1, axTicks(1), labels=F)
mtext(c("Apple\nSauce", "Banana\n", "Candy\n", "Dandelion\n", "Eve\n", "Fox\n"), 
      1, 2, at=axTicks(1))
```

[image]

**Edit:**

`spray` is a factor column and one factor is no longer needed, I'd do `drolevels`.

```
newInsectSprays <- InsectSprays[1:60,]
boxplot(count ~ spray, data=transform(newInsectSprays, spray=droplevels(spray)), 
        col="lightgray", xaxt="n")
mtext(c("Apple\nSauce", "Banana\n", "Candy\n", "Dandelion\n", "Eve\n"), 
      1, 2, at=axTicks(1))
```

[image]

**Edit2**

```
boxplot(count ~ droplevels(spray), 
        newInsectSprays[newInsectSprays$spray %in% c("A", "B", "C"), ], 
        xaxt="n", xlab="spray")
mtext(c("Apple\nSauce", "Banana\n", "Candy\n"), 1, 2, at=1:3)
```

[image]

Comment: @YQC Unused factor level issue, see edit. Use `str(newInsectSprays)` to check.

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a look at Edit2? I'm not sure why the labels are repeated even though there are only 3 boxplots.

Comment: @YQC I'm not exactly sure because I wouldn't code like that. However, basically the `at=` arguments are a sequence starting from 1, so try `mtext(c("Apple\nSauce", "Banana\n", "Candy\n"), 1, 2, at=1:3)`.

Comment: @YQC To reveal "code differently" see edit2, we may conveniently wrap `droplevels` around the sprays in the formula.